# How to set condition on function on the page load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this controller:

```
   (function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('damageEvent').controller("inspectionsDamageEventsController", ["siteId",                                                                         "mapguideService",
                                                                                    inspectionsDamageEventsController]);

    function inspectionsDamageEventsController(siteId, mapguideService, inspectionsDamageList) 
    {
       var self = this;
       this.siteId = siteId;
       this.mapguideService = mapguideService;
       this.isMapGuideEnabled = mapguideService.enabled;

       self.mapguideService.zoom("site", self.siteId);

    }
    })();
```

This row is fired on page loading:

```
 self.mapguideService.zoom("site", self.siteId);
```

I need to fire the row above on page load according to this value:

```
this.isMapGuideEnabled
```

If `isMapGuideEnabled` is true mapguideService.zoom() if fired otherwise not.

How can I set this condition on page load?

Answer (score 0):

`if` to the rescue ...

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('damageEvent').controller("inspectionsDamageEventsController", ["siteId",                                                                         "mapguideService",
                                                                                    inspectionsDamageEventsController]);

    function inspectionsDamageEventsController(siteId, mapguideService, inspectionsDamageList) 
    {
       var self = this;
       this.siteId = siteId;
       this.mapguideService = mapguideService;
       this.isMapGuideEnabled = mapguideService.enabled;

       if (this.isMapGuideEnabled) {
         self.mapguideService.zoom("site", self.siteId);
       }
    }
    })();
```